# Get compile errors for dependent TypeScript files in WebStorm

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, typescript, webstorm

I'm wondering if there is a way to make WebStorm show me compilation errors in dependent TypeScript files after an edit.  As an example, say I have `Class1.ts` as follows:

```
class Class1 {
    foo(n: number): number { return 3; }
}

export = Class1;
```

And also `Class2.ts`:

```
import Class1 = require('./Class1');

class Class2 extends Class1 {

    foo(n: number): number { return 4; }
}
```

Now, say I edit `Class1.ts` and change the parameter type of `foo`:

```
class Class1 {
    foo(n: string): number { return 3; }
}

export = Class1;
```

When I perform the edit and save, I don't see any new errors appear.  If I switch focus to the `Class2.ts` tab, at that point an "Incompatible override" message appears.  But ideally, I'd like some way to see all the errors I introduced in the whole project after making an edit.  Is there some view I can enable to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure if a way to do this automatically on save, but building the project seems to produce the errors for me.

Comment: @user1308743 thanks!  I'm still hoping that WebStorm can track dependencies and automatically recompile what's needed on save, though, like Eclipse JDT does for Java.

Comment: WebStorm does re-index files on each change and updates the errors/warnings shown in the editor as a result of code analysis. To see all these errors in a separate window, run Code/Inspect Code. But note that, unlike error marks in the Editor, this window doesn't auto-update when the file changes. So you need to invoke it explicitly each time you like to update it. You can assign some shortcut to this action and hit it, just like you hit Ctrl+S in Eclipse to get the Problems view updated:)

Comment: @user1308743 You say buiding the project does this for you where do you select building the project in Webstorm?

Answer (score 2):

Is using an external filewatcher an option for you?

I found the webstorm filewatcher for `typescript` to be a little buggy. As a result, I disabled the filewatcher and simpyly use `grunt-contrib-watch` in it's place. It works great, and provides a little more flexibility if you need it.

You could do something like this in your `gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var files = [
            'app/**/*.ts'
        ];

    grunt.initConfig({      
        tslint: {
            options: {
                configuration: grunt.file.readJSON("tslint.json")
            },
            files: {
                src: files
            }
        },
        typescript: {
            base: {
                src: files,
                options: {
                    module: 'commonjs',
                    target: 'es5'
                }
            },
            build: {
                src: ['./app.ts'],
                options: {
                    module: 'commonjs',
                    target: 'es5'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            ts: {
                files: ['app/**/*.ts', 'shared/**/*.ts'],
                tasks: ['typescript']
            }
        }
    });

    // Load Tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-tslint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // Register Tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);   
};
```

Then simply running `grunt` will perform the `watch` command, and you can eliminate the webstorm typescript filewatcher. This will give you build errors you are looking for on save.

*Note: I left `tslint` in the gruntfile as it's a good idea to run `tslint` on your files regularly, but it's certainly not necessary. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Cool!  Can compile errors still be navigated within WebStorm with this approach?

Comment: Absolutely. You'll still get all of the WebStorm features you expect - error highlighting, hover-over error messages, etc. The grunt watcher will also map back to the .ts files in your project, so you'll be able to see line numbers and file names for errors that way.

Comment: Ok, so I gave this a try, and it does show all compile errors in the terminal window where I ran 'grunt' when I save a file.  However, I don't see any errors popping up inside WebStorm.  Did I run 'grunt' incorrectly?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @ManuSridharan I think I misunderstood your earlier comment. The errors in WebStorm are not necessarily going to "pop up" like they would in the bottom window of WebStorm when you use the built in filewatcher. When you get an error in your terminal, it will come with a filename and line. You can then navigate to that file (⌘ + O on a mac) and you will see the error highlighted in red by default. So yes, when you are on the file in WebStorm you be able to identify the error easily. You will not necessarily have an "in your face" alert though, unless you have your terminal in front of you.

Comment: Ah, I see.  This is a nice improvement then, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  One option would be to run this in addition to the filewatcher, and that way, you'll still get immediate errors for the current file popping up in WebStorm (need to be careful about getting corrupted build output, though).  Anyway, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Still a manual process but better then guessing which files you need to open.

Select a project root folder, hit Ctrl+Shift+A -> Ctrl+Shift+A to enable non-menu actions -> type "run file " -> choose Run File Watchers....
This was part of an answer to another question.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/26779818/1757491)

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm now supports [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). You'll need to setup the tsconfig.json file and then go to File/Settings/Languages & Frameworks/TypeScript and check the 'Use tsconfig.json'. Once I did this I was able to (eventually) see type errors in the TypeScript Compiler window. The errors do not appear immediately like in Visual Studio. But for me they appear within 15 to 30 seconds. Also, another quick 'n dirty approach is to open a terminal window in the os or in WebStorm and type 'tsc --watch'. This tells the TypeScript compiler to compile everything immediately and shows you any errors. The '--watch' means that tsc (TypeScript compiler) will continue to monitor all .ts files and show any errors in the terminal window.